# Syntax Highlighting + Line Highlighting

Tags: syntax, syntax-highlighting

Is there any way to achieve both syntax highlighting and line highlighting for Rails?

Right now I've found several gems that achieve syntax highlighting, but it can't highlight specific lines.

Is there any way I could use a gem like pygments.rb and do something like this?

```
<%= raw Pygments.highlight('
class Car
  highlight(
    def initialize(size, color)
      @size = size
      @color = color
    end
  )
end
', lexer: 'ruby') %>
```

Comment: If you don't mind javascript-based syntax highlighter, I like to use PrismJS for syntax highlighting. 

It should have line-highlighting: https://github.com/oswaldoacauan/ghostium/issues/109#issuecomment-48852208

You can use gem `highlighting` for easy integration to rails.